One arm up pull up training deadhang strength
67.1kg 173 cm 26 yo male, 12 months of experience training spread across 8 years of training on and off, my longest streak was 3 and half months in a row and my heaviest weight ever was 76kg with enough definition to look good, but still, I was only strong in pulls:
I used to be able to do one arm pull ups... I started training again since exactly 32 days ago and I'm getting the strength back, I can do half reps one arm pull ups from a deadstop (feet on ground) so I can lift myself up to 90 degress and then slowly let myself down.
I can also do it if I kip up to go from dead hang to active hang and then do the one arm pull up half rep... but I can't pull myself from a dead hang to an active hang with one arm ,it just feels impossible.
My back is unbalanced, all lats, I'm wide as a kite and thin as a american cheese slices....Should I train my upper back more or just brute force thru it and just practice more my one arm chin ups?
Upper back musculature size is not a priority, getting the one arm pull up from full deadhang to chest to bar is the priority as of now...
i'm asking cause upper back strength training might add or detract to my goal, dunno which one tho

You should build up strength through a different veriaty of exercises and progressive overload without focussing too much on the fact that you want a single arm pullup as a result. Many people think that they need to do a one-arm-pullup, to train for one, this is not true.
I suggest adding weighted pullups to your training to add the overload needed to become strong enough to do a one-arm-pullup.
Do these weighted pullups with heavy weight for low reps, aim for 3-5 reps per set. This will build the strength to do 1 rep of a one-arm-pullup. On top of that, do negatives, train with resistance bands, to get the body used to the feel of a one-arm-pullup again.
Based on your question you also need to do partial reps for the range of motion that you struggle with the most.
Also, don't expect to be able to do a one-arm-pullup in a couple of sessions or weeks. This type of exercise is nearly impossible for most regular gymgoers, let alone training for a short period of time.
Expect to work on this for months before succesfully completing a single rep from a deadhang.

update, now I can do half reps from a  complete deadhang but end up rotating and losing strength at 90°
